# Handling exceptions in AsyncTask.doInBackground in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am following the [guide on Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) to implement an `AsyncTask` in an android activity in which I will perform some database access. However, my code has to handle an exception in `doInBackground`.

My current thinking is to provide a `Toast` popup to inform the user of this exception, but now I am afraid this too "*violates the second rule of the single-threaded model: do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread*" (as per the guide).

Would I be wrong in providing a Toast popup? Is there a better way to handle exceptions in the `doInBackground` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will the exception cause you to stop what `doInBackground` is processing?

If yes, store what exception you encountered, exit `doInBackground` and show the Toast in `onPostExecute`

If no, pass the exception information to `onProgressUpdate` with `publishProgress`.

Trying to pop-up the `Toast` in `doInBackground` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runOnUIThread` to update UI from background thread

```
  @Override
  protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   try{
        // do some stuff
    }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    final String message = ex.getMessage();
        yourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               // show toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

}